# Количество знаков после запятой c++

Tags: c++, c, вывод, форматирование

Нужно вывести результат деления двух чисел с точностью до 10^-9

Примеры:

```
19/7 - вывод 2.714285714
3/2 - вывод 1.5
8/2 - вывод 4.0
```

Если выводить с помощью СИшного `printf("%.9f", res)` - выводится `4.000000000, 1.500000000`
При выводе с помощью `std:::cout << res` - точность будет составлять лишь 10^-5 (вместо желаемого `2.714285714` при `19/7` выводится `2.71429`)

Comment: Ничего не понял. `8./2.` - это и есть `4.000000000`, а `3./2.` - это и есть `1.500000000`.  В чем проблема?

Comment: В постановке задачи. Мне нужен именно такой формат вывода, который я описал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cout << setprecision(10) << 19.0/7.0;
```

выведет

```
2.714285714
```

Смотрите всякие разности форматирования [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip).

Comment: Для 19 и 7 Ваш вариант сработал. Но есть 2 проблемы: 
при 8.0/2.0 выводит 4, а мне нужен вывод 4.0;
при, например, 40.0/3.0 выводит только 8 значений после запятой

Comment: Ну поднимите точность - она учитывает все знаки...

Answer (score 4):

1. Деление целочисленных дает целочисленное, остаток отсекается.
2. По умолчанию вещественные имеют тип данных `double`, в спецификации формата `printf()` он указывается как `%lf`.

Пример:

```
printf("%.9f",19.0F/7.0F);   // float       -> double
printf("%.9lf",19.0/7.0);    // double      -> double
printf("%.9Lf",19.0L/7.0L);  // long double -> long double
```

Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf) и [тут](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Comment: неверно... в `printf` `double` — это как раз `%f`, а `%Lf` — это уже `long double`. Спецификатора формата `%lf` в принципе нет....

Comment: преобразовывать в `double`... и да для `scanf`'а значения спецификаторов отличаются... это один из старых квирков Си...

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον Можно тоже как `%f`. При передаче `float` в сишный `...`-параметр он автоматически преобразуется в `double`. См. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Comment: @Fat-Zer Посмотрел cppreference. Там написано, что `%lf` есть (добавили в C++11/C99), и не отличается от `%f` (оба могут и в `float` и `double`).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да... моя ошибка... `%lf` — это тоже что и `%f` по всем стандартам....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10368369/13970074

Answer (score 3):

> Если выводить с помощью СИшного `printf("%.9f", res)`

Просто используй спецификатор %g:

```
printf("%.9g", 19./7); // 2.71428571                                                                                                                                                          
printf("%.9g",  3./2); // 1.5                                                                                                                                                                 
printf("%.9g",  8./2); // 4 
printf("%.9g", sqrt(10101)); //100.503731
```

Стоит помнить, что это `9` значащих цифр, а не 8 цифр после точки. Если нужно именно последнее, то можно сделать как-то так:

```
double res = sqrt(10101);
printf("%.*g\n", 8 + 1 + (int)log10(res), res); // 100.50373127
```